# Docusign WSDL link

Tags: docusignapi

What's the WSDL link for docusign? I found this:

https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?WSDL

But I want to make sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?WSDL` is the correct WSDL for Demo.

All of the information you need is in the [DocuSign SOAP API Guide](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm)
or the [PDF Version of the Guide](http://764be237d39fdfa0985f-37a6c1f0731907180d9764651d02bea9.r5.cf2.rackcdn.com/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf)